# Selenium grid only works one browser instance

Tags: selenium, docker, selenium-grid

I have configured a docker selenium hub with a docker selenium node firefox with 5 browser instances. When I launch two browsers only one of them is interacting, doing requests to the browser but the second one doesn't, giving a timeout. Once the first has finished starts the other one...Is there any parameter that I am missing?

```
Config for the hub :
browserTimeout : 0
debug : false
help : false
jettyMaxThreads : -1
port : 4444
role : hub
timeout : 120
enablePassThrough : true
cleanUpCycle : 5000
host : 172.18.0.2
maxSession : 5
hubConfig : /opt/selenium/config.json
capabilityMatcher : org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher
newSessionWaitTimeout : -1
throwOnCapabilityNotPresent : true
Config details :
hub launched with : -browserTimeout 0 -debug false -help false -
jettyMaxThreads -1 -port 4444 -role hub -timeout 120 -enablePassThrough true 
-cleanUpCycle 5000 -host 172.18.0.2 -maxSession 5 -hubConfig 
/opt/selenium/config.json -capabilityMatcher 
org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher -
newSessionWaitTimeout -1 -throwOnCapabilityNotPresent true
the final configuration comes from :
the default :
browserTimeout : 0
debug : false
help : false
port : 4444
role : hub
timeout : 1800
enablePassThrough : true
cleanUpCycle : 5000
capabilityMatcher : org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher
newSessionWaitTimeout : -1
throwOnCapabilityNotPresent : true

updated with params :
browserTimeout : 0
debug : false
help : false
jettyMaxThreads : -1
port : 4444
role : hub
timeout : 120
enablePassThrough : true
cleanUpCycle : 5000
maxSession : 5
capabilityMatcher : org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher
newSessionWaitTimeout : -1
throwOnCapabilityNotPresent : true
```

Comment: How are you starting your drivers?

Comment: DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
WebDriver browser = new RemoteWebDriver(
      new URL("http://"+server+":4444/wd/hub"),
      capabilities);

Comment: Update: if I configure with two nodes with one browser instance each, it works. With the same configuration (except maxSession and maxInstances obviously that are set to 1)